# How can I find the flag dependency or conflict in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, flags

As I know, GCC has this website to figure out the relationship between different flags using while optimization.  [GCC example website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). Like fpartialInlining can only be useful when findirectInlining is turned on.

I think the same thing would happen in clang, in other words, I think the different passes may have this kind of dependcy/confilcts relationship in LLVM(CLANG).

But after checking all the document provided by developers, I find it just say something about the functionality in these passes. [LLVM PASS DOC](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html)

So my question can be divided into 2 parts I think:

1. Does the dependency exists in LLVM PASS or there is no such dependency/conflicts
2. If there is, how can I find them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find which passes are using in which optimization levels by clang while compiling any c or c++ code with clang and try to figure out dependencies. For example:

```
clang -O2 --target=riscv32 -mllvm -debug-pass=Structure example.c
```

(You can use also `-debug-pass=Arguments` instead of `-debug-pass=Structure`. It depends readability.)

this will give which passes used by clang at 2. optimization level for riscv32 target. If you don't give a target it sets default as your host machine target, and keep in mind that some used passes changes related to different targets at same optimization levels.